# Possible to force the C# Facebook SDK to use HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to do some connectivity simulations to see that my code handles various connectivity errors to Facebook. I want to be able to simulate 500s, timeouts etc.

The easiest way to do that is to use Fiddler, but it seems to not be working with HTTPS (I get 403s when I try).

Is ther a way to force the SDK to work with HTTP instead of HTTPS for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK supports your scenario for mocking the entire HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. In fact we actually use that internally in our unit tests so that every single line of the code in Facebook C# SDK actually gets executed and the result is always the same. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/v5/Source/Facebook.Tests/TestExtensions.cs For now you will need to check these tests in v5 branch as we haven't yet migrated those tests to v6.

For v5, you will need to override the protected `CreateHttpWebRequest` method in FacebookClient.

Here is an example for v5 when there is no internet connection. There are three hidden classes HttpWebRequestWrapper, HttpWebResponseWrapper and WebExceptionWrapper that you will need to make use of.

```
    public static void NoInternetConnection(this Mock<Facebook.FacebookClient> facebookClient, out Mock<HttpWebRequestWrapper> mockRequest, out Mock<WebExceptionWrapper> mockWebException)
    {
        mockRequest = new Mock<HttpWebRequestWrapper>();
        mockWebException = new Mock<WebExceptionWrapper>();
        var mockAsyncResult = new Mock<IAsyncResult>();

        var request = mockRequest.Object;
        var webException = mockWebException.Object;
        var asyncResult = mockAsyncResult.Object;

        mockRequest.SetupProperty(r => r.Method);
        mockRequest.SetupProperty(r => r.ContentType);
        mockRequest.SetupProperty(r => r.ContentLength);
        mockAsyncResult
            .Setup(ar => ar.AsyncWaitHandle)
            .Returns((ManualResetEvent)null);

        mockWebException
            .Setup(e => e.GetResponse())
            .Returns<HttpWebResponseWrapper>(null);

        mockRequest
            .Setup(r => r.GetResponse())
            .Throws(webException);

        mockRequest
            .Setup(r => r.EndGetResponse(It.IsAny<IAsyncResult>()))
            .Throws(webException);

        AsyncCallback callback = null;

        mockRequest
            .Setup(r => r.BeginGetResponse(It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
            .Callback<AsyncCallback, object>((c, s) =>
                                                 {
                                                     callback = c;
                                                 })
            .Returns(() =>
                         {
                             callback(asyncResult);
                             return asyncResult;
                         });

        var mockRequestCopy = mockRequest;
        var mockWebExceptionCopy = mockWebException;

        facebookClient.Protected()
            .Setup<HttpWebRequestWrapper>("CreateHttpWebRequest", ItExpr.IsAny<Uri>())
            .Callback<Uri>(uri =>
                               {
                                   mockRequestCopy.Setup(r => r.RequestUri).Returns(uri);
                                   mockWebExceptionCopy.Setup(e => e.Message).Returns(string.Format("The remote name could not be resolved: '{0}'", uri.Host));
                               })
            .Returns(request);
    }
```

You can then write your tests as below.

```
    [Fact]
    public void SyncWhenThereIsNotInternetConnectionAndFiddlerIsNotOpen_ThrowsWebExceptionWrapper()
    {
        var mockFb = new Mock<FacebookClient> { CallBase = true };
        Mock<HttpWebRequestWrapper> mockRequest;
        Mock<WebExceptionWrapper> mockWebException;

        mockFb.NoInternetConnection(out mockRequest, out mockWebException);

        Exception exception = null;

        try
        {
            var fb = mockFb.Object;
            fb.Get(_parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        mockFb.VerifyCreateHttpWebRequest(Times.Once());
        mockRequest.VerifyGetResponse();
        mockWebException.VerifyGetReponse();

        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<WebExceptionWrapper>(exception);
    }
```

In v6 we have made mocking the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse much easier.

Create your custom HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse by inheriting `HttpWebRequestWrapper` and `HttpWebReponseWrapper`.

Then change the default http web request factory for Facebook C# SDK. Here is the sample of the default factory.

```
FacebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory(uri => new HttpWebRequestWrapper((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)));
```

If you want to change the HttpWebRequestFactor per FacebookClient instance then use the following code.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
fb.HttpWebRequestFactory = uri=> new MyHttpWebRequestWrapper(uri);
```

Note: HttpWebRequestWrapper, HttpWebResponseWrapper, WebExceptionWrapper, FacebookClient.SetDefaultHttpWebRequestFactory and FacebookClient.HttpWebRequestFactory has the attribute `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` so you might not see it in the intellisense.

Things like no internet connection that you mention should actually be a part of facebook c# sdk tests and not your app unit tests. The sdk should guarantee that when there is not internet conenction it always throws WebExceptionWrapper and your app unit tests should actually be handling the WebExceptionWrapper exception and not mocking the entire httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you introduce another level of abstraction to your code and code to that abstraction rather than the implementation. Eg.

```
public interface IFacebookClient {
  IEnumerable<Friend> GetFriends();
}

public class HttpsClient : IFacebookClient {
  public IEnumerable<Friend> GetFriends() {
    // Make a call out to the Facebook API, as per usual
  };
}
```

In your consuming code you'd do something like;

```
public class ConsumingCode {
  private IFacebookClient _client;

  public ConsumingCode(IFacebookClient client) {
    _client = client;

    foreach (Friend friend in _client.GetFriends()) {
      // Do something with each Friend
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using an IoC container this can all get wired up for you automatically. MVVM frameworks like Caliburn.Micro tend to support this as well.

Then when it comes to unit testing (or manual testing) you can change the implementation of your interface;

```
public class Http403Client : IFacebookClient {
  public IEnumerable<Friend> GetFriends() {
    throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
  }
}
```

Obviously this is just a mock up example but I think it demonstrates the concept that you want to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to test "real" bad responses coming from the web. My code seems sound, I already tested it with a method similar (though simpler) than what you suggest. The Facebook C# library though has a lot of code, and I need to see how it behaves in conjunction with my code when it gets bad HTTP responses.

Comment: At the end of the day it's still how your calling code responds to something the C# library is returning. If it's a specific situation - When I call GetFoo(), after I've called HasFoo(), something bad happens and I need to call Reset() - then build that scenario into your faked implementation. You might want to combine pass-through-calls to the real implementation and returning canned results / throwing in others depending on the scenario. But this sort of interaction testing is a great fit for automated unit tests.

Comment: Again, thanks - I appreciate your suggestion. But that's not an answer to my question and I am not interested in automated testing. I need to test a component I have little control over (the C# SDK) and the only ways I can do that, that I can see, is to either go in and add code to that component (which means I need to maintain my testing code inside a "living" component  or to make the component work against HTTP (so I can fake-failure in a one-off manual test). So again, it's a great suggestion for someone who would ask about automated testing, but I am not interested in that.